# Meteor.js: access Session variable from RouteController waitOn

Tags: session, meteor, coffeescript, iron-router

I need to access a Session Variable from a RouteController in the `waitOn` function in my meteor application, I set a session variable on the `onCreated` block in a template:

```
Template.practicalQuestionForm.onCreated ->
    Session.set 'domId', Random.id()
```

Then I need to access to that Session variable `Session.get 'domId'` from my controller, look at the `waitOn`:

```
@testsAddQuestionController = testsQuestionsController.extend
  template: ->
    qType = Router.current().params.type
    if qType == 'practical'
      'practicalQuestionForm'
    else if qType == 'mcq'
      'mcqQuestionForm'
  waitOn: ->
    console.log Session.get 'domId'
    Meteor.subscribe 'currentSessionUploads', Session.get 'domId'
  data: ->
    questions: TestQuestions.find()  
    test: Tests.findOne slug: this.params.slug
    previous: TestQuestions.find({}, sort: createdAt: 1, limit: 1).fetch().pop()
```

However I only get `undefined` can someone tell me if this is possible? if not what other alternatives do you can advise to me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `Session` in your `waitOn` function, you need to make sure that this code will be executed on the client.

For instance:

```
waitOn: function() {
  var domId = undefined;
  if(Meteor.isClient) {
    domId = Session.get('domId');
  }
  return Meteor.subscribe('currentSessionUploads', domId);
}
```

Please note that you need to check if `domId` is undefined in your publication (server-side).

Also You have to check that your `Session` variable is not already defined, otherwise you will get an infinite loop and your controller will get crazy:

```
Template.practicalQuestionForm.onCreated ->
    if not Session.get 'domId'
        Session.set 'domId', Random.id()
```

Comment: Thank you! I will test it, and reply. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi look I have a problem the waitOn gets into an infinite loop, so the template does not load, I check the domId session variable while running the palication and it is crazy it generates and generates random ids like crazy. Any idea'

Comment: Well, this may be attributed to your `onCreated` template handler. What if you generate the `domId` in your `onBeforeAction` function?

Comment: Hi thanks a lot I just had to check the that Session variable s not already defined, I added an if statement in the onCreated function and whoala, I edited your answer with this detail. =)